# User flair code is invalid for XHTML doctypes

Tags: bug, status-declined, flair, design, validation

The user flair HTML code displayed on the [user flair page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair) looks like this:

```
<a ... ><img ... ></a>
```

However, in order to validate in XHTML doctypes, it should really be:

```
<a ... ><img ... /></a>
```

Could this be changed on the user flair page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means it would be invalid for our doctype, so... no.

Comment: I thought it could go either way in 4.01, but of course didn't think to check... Validator only seems to throw a warning for it.

Comment: @jason there has been some talk of switching to the HTML 5 doctype but I'm unsure if that's safe or ready yet?

Comment: I would change too it @Jeff